# Keras ImageDataGenerator/flow_from_dir distorting image

Tags: python, keras

Keras's InputDataGenerator seems to be messing with the training data.

Here is the original image (128x128 w/ 3 colors):

[image: Dog]

And this is what I'm getting from the InputDataGenerator (128x128 w/ 3 colors):

[image]

Downloading the image directly wouldn't work with windows (said image was corrupt).

Anybody know what's going on and how to fix it?
It seems almost if every color is getting its own column or something weird like that.

```py
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

# Where ImageDataGenerator is getting data from
Data_Directory = 'C:/Users/user/PycharmProjects/ImageGAN/training/'

# Actual image location; Img is (128, 128, 3).
Image_location = r'C:/Users/user/PycharmProjects/ImageGAN/training/class1/dog.png'

datagen = ImageDataGenerator()
train_ds = datagen.flow_from_directory(Data_Directory, target_size=(128, 128))

data = train_ds.next()
imgdata = np.array(data[0])

print(imgdata.shape)        # (1, 128, 128, 3)
print(imgdata[0][0][55])    # [115. 80. 38.]

# Distorted image
img = Image.fromarray(imgdata[0], "RGB")
img.save(f"DogBroken.png")
img.show()

# Correct image
image = Image.open(Image_location).convert("RGB")
image.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to keep the same dimension you should change the `target_size` arguments of the method [`flow_from_directory`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image/ImageDataGenerator#flow_from_directory). In your case:

```
train_ds = datagen.flow_from_directory(Data_Directory, target_size=(128, 128))
```

To fix the issue apply `.astype('uint8')` to the numpy array:

```
img = Image.fromarray(imgdata[0].astype('uint8'), "RGB")
```

`.astype('uint8')` is used to convert the values to unsigned integers.